# CSS changes automatically after logging out of WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am creating Template for WordPress. My CSS works fine when I am logged in, but when I log out the CSS changes. Is there any way that I can achieve the same effect while logged in or out? I am not using different CSS for logged in or logged out users; it should be the same CSS for both.

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching? Some caching plugins will not use the cache for logged in users, which would explain why what you see while logged in doesn't match what you see while logged out.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply ,I am not using any caching plugin

Comment: You should try posting some code. How are you enqueuing your stylesheet?

Comment: Hi,I am using Studiopress genesis as base template

Comment: What has been changed exactly? so when you logged in there will be a black bar at the top, and that would be gone after logged out.

Comment: Have you checked functions.php for anything specific to a logged in status?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed admin bar by using this code `show_admin_bar(false);` in `functions.php` and now everything works fine ,Thanks for the help guys

Comment: That's nice that you did that, but it is entirely unhelpful considering that you haven't shared any code with us. Either edit your question so that this answer makes sense or delete the question.

Comment: I shared code ,please put  `show_admin_bar(false);` in your functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Simple

If all your files located correct and css files too then just press **CTRL+F5** and it will work.

CSS issue special happens in godaddy wordpress managed account.

Note- **If css save in wp-content/uploads/xyz.css then after migration it will go to theme/css/custom-style.css .** You dont have to make any changes in urls..Just make correction or update css in theme/css/custom-style.css